# Photo Gallery - Dynamically Determine the width/height of an Image to Maximize the view

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm building a photo gallery. The photo gallery consists of images that users upload. These uploads are resized, and can be of any dimension, 100x100, 2500x2500.

My Photo Gallery View page is Fluid, meaning the width of the page is not fixed.

In the Photo Gallery page I display the original Image updated - no resizing ( though I do for other purposes, thumbnails etc)...

What I would like to do, is show the image at the maximum possible dimension to use all the real-estate of the page possible.

Right now I have:
    max-width: 600px;
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;

Problem is if I get rid of max-width, then the image overflows off the page.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Giving dimensions of max-width and max-height in percentage might help.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry , I cant understand what u want exactly but
 to determine the width of element in jquery

```
var wid=$('#id').width();
```

u can change the width of the image dynamically using(assuming you need 100X100)

```
 var x=100;
 $(#id).css({width:x,height:x});
```

Comment: what I'm trying to do is maximize the size of an image based on the fluid width of a DIV

Comment: u can do that by using the above two  thats why i have provided them take the width if div from first one (var x=$('div').width();
) and use it in the second one ($(#id).css({width:x,height:x});
)